Generating TOTP using OTPAuth library on Nodejs
I do face some problem while generating TOTP by OTPAuth library on Nodejs. Sometimes, time on my devices is not correct, so it led to the incorrect in TOTP generated. I can prevent it by set the right time for my device.
I wonder do we have any way to make sure that the OTPAuth library generate based on the correct time not by manually set time on device?

what device these days doesn't synchronise with NTP? having said that, timezonedb could help

based on my organization's policy, we can not sync up with NTP, no idea about that

actually, never mind, since OTPAuth doesn't allow you to specify the time

so it means that i have no solution to generated TOTP based on specific time?

I didn't say that, I said knowing the correct time (using something like the api I mentioned) won't help you do it with OTPAuth - but TOTP is a simple algorithm - less than 50 lines in nodejs
